# Find out the unicode character code of icon-font icons

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

I have a font file called `icon-font.woff`, and I have the corresponding SVG file. It has some number of icons inside. now i would like to use these icons in my html file using css like this:

```
.icon-add-contact:before{content:""}
```

But I don't know what is the value I need to give in the `content` above. And I don't know which value goes to which icon.

How to handle this?

Comment: a little google search came up with this: http://gomakethings.com/icon-fonts/  hope it helps

Comment: you only have the .woff file? Or do you have the icons as svg as well?

Comment: yes, i have svg as well. but not always to every fonts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](https://helloanselm.com/2014/parsing-iconfont-characters-automatically/), you should be able to find the unicode codes inside the SVG files of your font. In there, you should see something like this:

```
<glyph unicode="!" horiz-adv-x="100" d="M83.522656250000011
              38.628515624999999 C85.970996093749989 38.628515625000006
              90.867675781250000 38.628515625000006 93.316015624999977
              38.628515625000006 C94.026953124999977 38.628515625000006
              94.737695312500023 z" />
```

The unicode attribute will tell you what the code is, in this case it's `!`, but generally it will be something like `\f179`. This unicode code is what you will need to put after `content:`.

The [article by Anselm Hannemann](https://helloanselm.com/2014/parsing-iconfont-characters-automatically/) (same link as above) describes a method to create an HTML table that will display each icon next to its code.

Comment: i see my unicode like this : `unicode="&#xE008;"` - I taken this all, but not working. then i taken `E008` - as well no luck

Comment: Try `'\E008'` - compare this: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

Comment: yes, it is works. In case if I couldn't have the `svg` - file then it is very difficult to read the `unicode`

Comment: @KWeiss, the magic translator is Unicode=`"&#xE008;"` --> `"\E008"`... way helpful.  Many thx. Note, the Anselm Hanneman link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way:
Get the URL of the icon font (usually a .woff), replace it with the "ttf" extension. Download that using your browser and install the font.
Open the character map, choose the font and browse the characters. you either copy the character or use the unicode character it shows you.
On Windows you can as well open MS Word or Outlook, choose "Insert -> Symbol" to get the character map.